# Strange error building crosstool-ng for mipsel architecture under Alpine in Docker

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, crosstool-ng

As the title says, I get a strange error building crosstool-ng for mipsel architecture under Alpine in Docker. Any ideas? To me it looks like some kind of incompatibility between the host toolchain and the target toolchain but I'm no expert in this sort of thing.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.10.2
RUN apk add bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN apk add build-base
RUN set -o xtrace ; set -o errexit ; set -o nounset ; set -o pipefail ; mkdir -p /opt/ctng ; cd /opt/ctng ; wget http://crosstool-ng.org/download/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng-1.24.0.tar.bz2 ; [ "$(sha256sum ./crosstool-ng-1.24.0.tar.bz2 | cut -d " " -f 1)" == "d200d1ea5e2056c60d2b11b3f2721d30e53e817e1e0050fffaca074864e2f523" ] ; tar -xf ./crosstool-ng-1.24.0.tar.bz2 ; mv ./crosstool-ng-1.24.0 ./ctng
RUN apk add flex
RUN apk add texinfo
RUN apk add xz
RUN apk add help2man
RUN apk add gawk
RUN apk add libtool
RUN apk add ncurses-dev
RUN apk add gettext-dev
RUN apk add wget
RUN apk add patch
RUN apk add bison
RUN apk add libc-dev
RUN set -o xtrace ; set -o errexit ; set -o nounset ; set -o pipefail ; cd /opt/ctng/ctng ; ./configure --enable-local ; make
RUN set -o xtrace ; set -o errexit ; set -o nounset ; set -o pipefail ; cd /opt/ctng/ctng ; ./ct-ng mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu ; echo -n -e "CT_EXPERIMENTAL=y\nCT_ALLOW_BUILD_AS_ROOT=y\nCT_ALLOW_BUILD_AS_ROOT_SURE=y\n" >>./.config ; mkdir -p /root/src ; time ./ct-ng build CT_JOBS=`nproc`
```

Here is the relevant `build.log` output:

```
[ALL  ]      x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu-gcc  -O2 -g -I/opt/ctng/ctng/.build/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/buildtools/include    -D_GNU_SOURCE -DIS_IN_build -include /opt/ctng/ctng/.build/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/build/build-libc-startfiles/multilib/config.h rpc_parse.c     -o /opt/ctng/ctng/.build/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/build/build-libc-startfiles/multilib/sunrpc/cross-rpc_parse.o -MMD -MP -MF /opt/ctng/ctng/.build/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/build/build-libc-startfiles/multilib/sunrpc/cross-rpc_parse.o.dt -MT /opt/ctng/ctng/.build/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/build/build-libc-startfiles/multilib/sunrpc/cross-rpc_parse.o -c
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:78:9: error: unknown type name '__u_char'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_char u_char;
[ALL  ]               ^~~~~~~~
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:78:18: error: conflicting types for 'u_char'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_char u_char;
[ALL  ]                        ^~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc/types.h:69,
[ALL  ]                       from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ALL  ]      /usr/include/sys/types.h:64:23: note: previous declaration of 'u_char' was here
[ALL  ]       typedef unsigned char u_char;
[ALL  ]                             ^~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:79:9: error: unknown type name '__u_short'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_short u_short;
[ALL  ]               ^~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:79:19: error: conflicting types for 'u_short'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_short u_short;
[ALL  ]                         ^~~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc/types.h:69,
[ALL  ]                       from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ALL  ]      /usr/include/sys/types.h:65:24: note: previous declaration of 'u_short' was here
[ALL  ]       typedef unsigned short u_short, ushort;
[ALL  ]                              ^~~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:80:9: error: unknown type name '__u_int'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_int u_int;
[ALL  ]               ^~~~~~~
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:80:17: error: conflicting types for 'u_int'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_int u_int;
[ALL  ]                       ^~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc/types.h:69,
[ALL  ]                       from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ALL  ]      /usr/include/sys/types.h:66:18: note: previous declaration of 'u_int' was here
[ALL  ]       typedef unsigned u_int, uint;
[ALL  ]                        ^~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:81:9: error: unknown type name '__u_long'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_long u_long;
[ALL  ]               ^~~~~~~~
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:81:18: error: conflicting types for 'u_long'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_long u_long;
[ALL  ]                        ^~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc/types.h:69,
[ALL  ]                       from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ALL  ]      /usr/include/sys/types.h:67:23: note: previous declaration of 'u_long' was here
[ALL  ]       typedef unsigned long u_long, ulong;
[ALL  ]                             ^~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:82:9: error: unknown type name '__quad_t'
[ALL  ]       typedef __quad_t quad_t;
[ALL  ]               ^~~~~~~~
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:82:18: error: conflicting types for 'quad_t'
[ALL  ]       typedef __quad_t quad_t;
[ALL  ]                        ^~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc/types.h:69,
[ALL  ]                       from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ALL  ]      /usr/include/sys/types.h:68:19: note: previous declaration of 'quad_t' was here
[ALL  ]       typedef long long quad_t;
[ALL  ]                         ^~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:83:9: error: unknown type name '__u_quad_t'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_quad_t u_quad_t;
[ALL  ]               ^~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:83:20: error: conflicting types for 'u_quad_t'
[ALL  ]       typedef __u_quad_t u_quad_t;
[ALL  ]                          ^~~~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc/types.h:69,
[ALL  ]                       from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ALL  ]      /usr/include/sys/types.h:69:28: note: previous declaration of 'u_quad_t' was here
[ALL  ]       typedef unsigned long long u_quad_t;
[ALL  ]                                  ^~~~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:84:9: error: unknown type name '__fsid_t'
[ALL  ]       typedef __fsid_t fsid_t;
[ALL  ]               ^~~~~~~~
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:88:9: error: unknown type name '__daddr_t'
[ALL  ]       typedef __daddr_t daddr_t;
[ALL  ]               ^~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:89:9: error: unknown type name '__caddr_t'
[ALL  ]       typedef __caddr_t caddr_t;
[ALL  ]               ^~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]      rpc/types.h:89:19: error: conflicting types for 'caddr_t'
[ALL  ]       typedef __caddr_t caddr_t;
[ALL  ]                         ^~~~~~~
[ALL  ]      In file included from rpc/types.h:69,
[ALL  ]                       from rpc_parse.c:39:
[ALL  ]      /usr/include/sys/types.h:63:15: note: previous declaration of 'caddr_t' was here
[ALL  ]       typedef char *caddr_t;
[ALL  ]                     ^~~~~~~
[ERROR]      make[3]: *** [Makefile:174: /opt/ctng/ctng/.build/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/build/build-libc-startfiles/multilib/sunrpc/cross-rpc_parse.o] Error 1
[ERROR]      make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ALL  ]      make[3]: Leaving directory '/opt/ctng/ctng/.build/src/glibc-2.28/sunrpc'
[ERROR]      make[2]: *** [Makefile:258: sunrpc/install-headers] Error 2
[ALL  ]      make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/ctng/ctng/.build/src/glibc-2.28'
[ERROR]      make[1]: *** [Makefile:9: install-headers] Error 2
[ALL  ]      make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/ctng/ctng/.build/mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu/build/build-libc-startfiles/multilib'
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Building for multilib 1/1: '''
[ERROR]  >>        called in step 'Installing C library headers & start files'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
```

Comment: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=10151&action=edit

Comment: @Adiii Good find. Maybe someone will come along and elaborate that into an answer, hopefully explaining how to integrate the patch into the build process of crosstool-ng.

Comment: Ah well, took the easy road and fixed this building on ubuntu instead. It might also work to disable the sunrpc config option (haven't tried this).

Comment: Were you able to fix this?